# AttributeError: type object 'Message' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

> AttributeError: type object 'Message' has no attribute 'get'

Code:

```
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
labelText = StringVar()

display = Label(frame, textvariable=labelText)
labelText.set("Connecting to the server...")
display.pack()
frame.pack()
display.update()


def Submit_Message(event):
    Message_Get = Message.get()
    print(Message_Get)

def run_code_1():
    print("Enter Message to send!")
    Message = StringVar()
    Message = Text(root)
    Submit_Data_Button = Button(root, text="Submit")
    Submit_Data_Button.bind("<Button-1>", Submit_Message)
    Submit_Data_Button.pack()
    Message.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)


run_code_1()

root.mainloop()
```

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1699, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "D:\python_projects\trial2.py", line 42, in
>   Submit_M essage
>       Message_Get = Message.get() AttributeError: type object 'Message' has no attribute 'get'
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 5.439 s Press any key
>   to continue . . .

Comment: The code you posted doesn't give the error you say it does. It would help if you showed the complete traceback, and an [mcve] that creates the traceback. Also, you tagged this with `tkinter-entry` but you aren't using an `Entry`, you're using a `Text` widget.

Comment: It would improve the quality of your question if you also removed all of the non-relevant code, such as all of the unnecessary imports (selenium, socket, uuid, etc). None of that, nor code like setting the geometry, title, or resizable attributes is related to the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

in your def method you need to say what Message is. You only do that outside the method. Message has not been initialised in your Submit_Message method, therefore it does not have any attributes. You can make it global for example

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating a *local* variable named `Message`. However, `Submit_Message` cannot see that local variable. Instead, it thinks that `Message` is the global class that you imported with `from tkinter import *`

If you need to access your local `Message` variable in other contexts, you need to make it global by adding `global Message` inside of `run_code_1`.

Comment: Got error: ***AttributeError: type object 'Message' has no attribute 'get'*** while trying: `global Message
    Message = StringVar()
    Message = Text(root)`

Comment: @Komal: literally, if you add `global Message` inside `run_code_1`, you will not get that error. Though, adding confusion to the problem is that a) you're importing `Message` from tkinter, b) you're using `Message` to refer to a `StringVar`, and you're also using `Message` to refer to the text widget.

Comment: When I tried [this code](https://pastebin.com/pJqc26y3), I got: ***TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'***

Comment: @Komal: yes, that is a different problem then the one you asked about. You can solve that problem by reading the documentation on the `Text` widget `get` method.